# Why is Node.js fs.statSync birthtime in Node.js off?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, date, datetime

I have two questions that I haven't seen answers for on this matter, nor do I recall a heads up in the docs.

1. Why are `fs.statSync` datetime stamps such as `birthtime` all off and not matching what I see when I view the files manually in my OS (which shows the correct datetimes)?
2. How do I get the *EXACT* correct times, exactly as they are shown on the file itself?  I know the dates and times are correct when I view it in the OS because I was there for the photo.  Just don't know what to do to make Node.js give me the times as they really were/are.

Here's my *correct* output in the OS (Windows in this case, but it needs to work the same in all OSs):

[image]

[image]

Here's the call I'm making within seconds of the other:

```
const stats = fs.statSync(absPathOfFile);
const dates = [
    stats.birthtime,
    stats.ctime,
    stats.mtime,
    stats.atime,
];
```

And that Node.js output:

```
[
  2022-10-31T08:47:00.900Z,
  2022-06-13T05:37:42.128Z,
  2022-04-12T04:55:49.070Z,
  2022-10-31T08:47:02.027Z
]
```

So all of those dates are off.  I was expecting Node.js to return the actual dates/times as listed in the file's meta data.

Comment: Which OS is this? Which file system is this? How are you determining birthtimes "manually in your OS"?

Comment: @AKX Just updated my question to reflect more details with the full example.

Comment: "Date Taken" is EXIF metadata that is read from the image file itself and has nothing to do with `birthtime`. `birthtime` is documented in the Node docs (emphasis mine): "Time of file creation. Set once when the file is created. On filesystems **where birthtime is not available, this field may instead hold either the ctime or 0**. This value may be greater than atime or mtime in this case. On Darwin and other FreeBSD variants, [...]".

Comment: @AKX I guess there's two questions there: 1) How would I get the EXIF metadata in that case, 2) to my original question, why are the other times off too? I get that some are based on the moment I copied the file and seem like they're clearly offset, and the other dates are off too.

Comment: (1) With e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/exif (I just googled for npm exif, YMMV) (2) In the ISO8601 format, `Z` means the formatted date is in UTC. Windows is showing you local time (I'd wager Utah time based on your profile), Node isn't.

Comment: @AKX I don't want to pull in libraries, but I saw the same thing, a lot of variables and packages for that. It sounds like that's where I need to dig in more. That's really too bad those dates are not standardized as the birthtime. Thank you for the info on that and the UTC offset.

Comment: If you don't want to pull in libraries (why not?), you can of course write an Exif parser yourself, but it'll be some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the comment discussion an answer:

- `birthtime` is not necessarily available on all file systems, and how the `atime`/`mtime`/`ctime`/`birthtime` fields map to file system properties depends. [Node.js docs here.](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#stat-time-values)
- The "Date Taken" that Windows (and maybe other OSes) shows is [Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) metadata pulled from the file's internal data itself, and is not related to a filesystem date. (IOW, moving the file around or resetting its times with e.g. `touch` or other calls doesn't affect it.)
- The dates returned by `statSync` are in UTC time (which is evident from the [`Z` time zone specifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)) in the ISO8601 formatted output). Windows shows the dates in the user's local time zone.